# How do I prove that the integral of f on [-a,a] is equal to two times the integral of f on [0,a]?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification, proof-writing, riemann-integration

The question is this:
Let f be an integrable function on [-a,a] (a>0). Assume f is an even function (i.e. f(-x) = f(x)) for all x ∈ [-a,a]. Then use the definition of an integral to prove $\int_{-a}^a f = 2\int_{0}^a f$.
We need to show that U(f,P) = 2 U(f,P+) and L(f,P) = 2 L(f,P+).
Could someone help with my proof?

**My take on the proof**:
Consider a partition P+ = {0 = t0 < t1 < ... < tn = a} of [0, a] and a partition P_ = {-a = -tn < ... < -t1 < -t0 = 0} of [-a,0] such that U(f,P+) - L(f,P+) = ε/2 and U(f,P_) - L(f,P_) = ε/2.

Let P = P+ + P_ then P is a partition of [-a,a]. We have:

L(f) ≥ L(f, P) = L(f, P+) + L(f,P_) > U(f, P+) + U(f, P_) − ε and
U(f) ≤ U(f, P) = U(f, P+) + U(f, P_) < L(f, P+) + L(f, P_) + ε

Because P+ is the inverse of P_, P = 2P+. Hence, L(f) ≥ L(f, P) = 2 L(f, P+) and U(f) ≥ U(f, P) = 2 U(f, P+). From here, I know that we need to show the inequality of 2 L(f,P+) ≤ $\int_{-a}^a f$ ≤ 2 U(f,P+) but I am not sure how to set it up. Could someone help me to check if what I did so far is correct and show how I can move on to proving this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Alternatively, $\int_{-a}^a = \int_{-a}^0 + \int_0^{a}$ make this a little easier.

Comment: Why not show that $L(f,P+)=L(f,P\_)$, and similarly for upper sums? The symmetry holds for each mirrored pair of subintervals.

Comment: Incidentally, a more standard notation might be $P^+$ and $P^-$